# Replace words with html elements

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on a Twitter program and am stuck on how to replace words with html elements.  For example:

Replace:
`Hello #World, This is a Tweet!`

With: `Hello <a href="">#World</a>, this is a Tweet!`

I know that you can use regex in `replace()` but I am unsure of how to reference to the matched string after in the second argument of `replace()`

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regular expression

```
str="Hello #World"
str.replace(/#(\S*)/g,'<a href="">$1</a>');
```